# Concatenating integers to const char* strings

Tags: c++

I have a few files named like so: `file1`, `file2`, `file3`, etc.

I have a function:

```
load(const char *file)
```

which I would call like so `load(file1)`, `load(file2)`, etc.

I am trying do this a bit more dynamically, based on the number of files imported.

So if I have more than 1 file do something like this:

```
if (NUM_OF_FILES > 1) {
    for (int i = 2; i <= NUM_OF_FILES; i++) {
        load("file" + i);
    }
}
```

However, this is not working.

Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: `"file" + std::to_string(i)`

Comment: done `load("file" + std::to_string(i))` and I get this `cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' to 'const char *'`

Comment: remember, c++ is static typed, so you can not add/concat different type of data.

Comment: In that case, `("file" + std::to_string(i)).c_str()`.

Comment: @sunny1304 You can do `const char * + int` but the results won't be what the OP was intending (equivalent here would be `&("file"[i])`). Also it's not really related to "static types" as much as it is related to the definition of the `+` operator in that context.

Comment: @JasonC, b0Gd4N seemed to be new in c++, thats why i wnated to generalize the idea, but obviously you are right.

Comment: I edited to `load (const char *file)` as I am presuming that was a typo when asking the question. (If it weren't, the OP would not have gotten to the point he needed to be at to ask this question in the first place.)

Comment: @b0Gd4N: No problem. Beware that the lifetime of that string is only the statement itself and no longer, so don't go storing the char pointer anywhere. It won't be valid after the statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type of a string literal like `"file"` is `char const[N]` (with a suitable `N`) whic happily decays into a `char const*` upon the first chance it gets. Although there is no addition defeined between `T[N]` and `int`, there is an addition defined between `char const*` and `int`: it adds the `int` to the pointer. That isn't quite what you want.

You probably want to convert the `int` into a suitable `std::string`, combine this with the string literal you got, and get a `char const*` from that:

```
load(("file" + std::to_string(i)).c_str());
```

Comment: @Steger: not the parenthesis: `std::to_string()` return a `std::string` which is concatenated to `"file"` yielding another `std::string`. The `.c_str()` is used to extract a `char const*` from the resulting `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what version of C++ you are using. If it's C++11, the solution will involve `std::to_string`. If it's an older version of C++, you can convert an integer to a string like this:

```
#include <sstream>

// ...

std::ostringstream converter;
converter << i; // i is an int
std::string s(convert.str());
```

Now, the `load` function takes a `const char *`. Is it your own function? Then consider changing it so that it takes a `std::string const&` instead, and you'll be able to pass the string directly. Otherwise, this is how can pass the string's contents to it:

```
load(s.c_str());
```

Comment: load() is not my own function. it is part of a library I am using

Comment: @b0Gd4N: No problem at all, you'll be fine with `c_str()`, which is designed to make C++ strings compatible with C or C-style functions.